# Cannot change dynos on Heroku dashboard

Tags: heroku

After having used the Heroku server successfully many times now I am consistently getting this error:

at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=rand-dyl-test.herokuapp.com request_id=b900df9f-c6cc-4b5e-a776-aff2ce92fd35 fwd="134.117.121.232" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

From what I understand this is something related to the dynos, but I cannot adjust these in the configuration on oTree hub or from the dashboard on Heroku.

I have tried some things that I saw suggest online regarding the Procfile but this is, frankly, over my head. I am really at a loss for what to do next. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As you are mentioning the Procfile, you may find it very useful to create one to see if that fixes the part of `No web processes running`.

A Procfile are just the commands your Dynos are going to execute in order to boot up your program, you can create one by just naming it “Procfile” and placing it on the root of your project folder.

For example, if you have a Node.js app or similar:

```
Worker: npm run deploy
```

This will create a Worker Dyno that deploys the app whenever a new version is created.

You may also need to manually activate your Dyno on your Dashboard to make sure it is running.

You can read more about the Procfile [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)